# Laravel 5.2 - eloquent relations

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables one is `templates` and the other is `template_images`

Showing migration of the two tables.

**Templates**

```
Schema::create('templates', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title', 155);
            .....
});
```

**Template Images**

```
Schema::create('template_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('template_id')->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('master');
            $table->binary('image');
$table->foreign('template_id')->references('id')->on('templates')->onDelete('cascade');
            ...
        });
```

I have made relations in the both `Models` like this

**Template-Model**

```
class Template extends Model
{
public function tempImage()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TemplateImage', 'template_id');
    }
}
```

**Template Image-Model**

```
class TemplateImage extends Model
{
public function tempImage ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Template', 'template_id');
    }
}
```

What I want is

Select all from templates and select from template_images where template_images.template_id = templates.id and template_images.master = 1

**Update**
This is how I need to get the image in blade

```
$temp->tempImage->image
```

What I try in my controller

```
$temps = Template::query()->with('tempImage')->get();
```

but still cant get it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

class Template extends Model
{
    public function tempImages()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TemplateImage', 'template_id');
  }

  public function tempMasterImage(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\TemplateImage', 'template_id')->where('master', 1);    
  }
}
```

If every template can only have 1 master template image then it's better to create a separate relation in model for that. See the example model Class above. `tempMasterImgage()` is the new relation and it has `hasOne` relation with TemplateImage. With this in place you can simply do.

```
$template->tempMasterImage->image
```

from anywhere, You just need access to Template  object.

**Edit**
It's better to name your hasMany relationship function as plural. That's why I used `tempImages` in my example

**Example Usage.**

```
$template = Template::with(['tempImages', 'tempMasterImage'])->first();

//if you want tempImages to exclude masterImage as we have now seperate relation for that then
$template = Template::with(['tempImages' => function($query){
    $query->where('master', '<>', 1);
}])->with('tempMasterImage')->first();

//get master image
$template->tempMasterImage->image

//get all images
foreach($template->tempImages as $tempImage){
    echo $tempImage->image // 
}
```

Comment: Yes this was really good and 1+ for this answer, but still need to know how to get it by query in case I need to access the other ones like `master = 2` thanks

Comment: See the edit. In your migration, master is a boolean column so I am assuming it can only have two states. provided usages based on this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If your `$temp` variable is an instance of model Template, you can not do `$temp->tempImage->image` becouse tempImage is a hasMany relationship.

So you can do two things, first:

```
$temps = Template::with(['tempImage' => function($query){
        $query->where('master',1);
    }])->get();
```

And then in your view

```
foreach ($temps as $temp) 
{
      foreach ($temp->tempImage as $temp_image) 
      {
        // Here your code for $temp_image->image
      }
}
```

Or second

```
$temps = TemplateImage::where('master',1)->with('tempImage')->get();
```

And then in your view

```
foreach ($temps as $temp) 
{
        // Here your code for $temp->image
}
```

Comment: first thanks for replaying, but when try the first query I got
`Undefined variable: query`

Comment: Also I need to get the `master = 1` but in blade I don't want to loop just the first() will do.

Comment: I forgot to add `$quey` on function, I updated the answer but if you only have one with `master = 1`, solution 2 will be better or use Ankit solution :)